# Search for GPO link inside an XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, gpo

I am trying to perform a search in the XML file in order to check if a specific group policy is linked to a few OUs.

The format of the OU is **"OU=XXXXX-Name,OU=DEMO OU,dc=domain,dc=local"**

I managed to get the full distinguishedname property of each OU and i kept only the first part of it

**OU=XXXXX-Name**,

discarding the rest and the "OU=" part so i am left with the display name which i need

I am a bit confused while struggling to create an "If condition" where i am using the

```
GPO-Report -XML
```

output to search and check the value in section and see if it matches with the target OU name so i can determine if the GPO is already linked to the specific OU

The XML file has the section below

```
<LinksTo>
        <SOMName>XXXXX-Name</SOMName>
        <SOMPath>domain.local/DEMO OUs</SOMPath>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <NoOverride>false</NoOverride>
      </LinksTo>
```

Any help would be much appreciated cause i ve spend a good amount of hours circling around this issue, trying to figure out how regular expressions will help me achieve that.

PS I am not an expert in code but i try my best to get into it.

I have tried a few regular expression examples without any luck.

**UPDATE**

Apologies for the incomplete post (i am still new in here)

I think i managed to make it work by adding 2 lines of code. My code as follows:

```
    Clear-Host
    $gpoName = "TestGPO"
    
    $oulist=(Get-Content C:\temp\ou.txt|foreach {
        Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "name -like `"*$_*`"" -Properties distinguishedname|`
select -ExpandProperty distinguishedname}) -replace '^OU=|,.*$'
        $xmlgpo=Get-GPO $gpoName |Get-GPOReport -ReportType XML
        
    foreach ($item in $oulist){
        if ($xmlgpo -match $item){
        Write-Warning "GPO '$gponame' has a link already to '$item'"
        }
           else{
               Write-Warning "No link to OU '$item' found"
           }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your PowerShell script too

Comment: `[xml]$xml = get-content report.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I would write code like this to create a Powershell Table.

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$links = $xDoc.Descendants("LinksTo").Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])

$pattern = '^(?<domain>[^.]+)\.(?<host>[^/]+)/(?<value>.*)'

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($link in $links)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject

   $SOMName = $link.Element("SOMName").Value   
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName SOMName -NotePropertyValue $SOMName

   $SOMPath = $link.Element("SOMPath").Value 
   $matches = $SOMPath | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
   $domain = $matches.Matches.groups[1].value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName domain -NotePropertyValue $domain
   $_host = $matches.Matches.groups[2].value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName host -NotePropertyValue $_host
   $value = $matches.Matches.groups[3].value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName value -NotePropertyValue $value

   $Enabled = $link.Element("Enabled").Value   
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Enabled -NotePropertyValue $Enabled

   $NoOverride = $link.Element("NoOverride").Value   
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName NoOverride -NotePropertyValue $NoOverride

   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback although i think i managed to find a solution to my problem by adding a line or two

Answer (score 0):

I decided to turn my question into an answer since i managed to ma ke the code work
Thank you all for your time

```
    Clear-Host
    $gpoName = "TestGPO"
    
    $oulist=(Get-Content C:\temp\ou.txt|foreach {
        Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "name -like `"*$_*`"" -Properties distinguishedname|`
        select -ExpandProperty distinguishedname}) -replace '^OU=|,.*$'

    $xmlgpo=Get-GPO $gpoName |Get-GPOReport -ReportType XML
        
    foreach ($item in $oulist){
        if ($xmlgpo -match $item){
        Write-Warning "GPO '$gponame' has a link already to '$item'"
        }
           else{
               Write-Warning "No link to OU '$item' found"
           }
    }
```